# H.264 Codecs on Chromium Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, linux-mint, chromium, codec

I have been using Chromium for a while, but I found was that I can't watch Netflix because the H.264 codecs are not available. I have already done some research on this, but nothing works. I have tried:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

`sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg`

`sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`(This is the one I am currently using since `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` and `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` are not allowed to be installed together)

(The Above install fine)

`sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree Which is not found.`

I have also tried to install `libnss3`, `libnss3-1d`, and `libnss3-nssdb`, but it didn't work. I also tried getting the repository(`ppa:lenobo/nss`) but it gives something about it not supporting bionic.




I am using Linux Mint 19.3 64-bit (Based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) but Ubuntu solutions should work just fine. I am also using Chromium 83.0.4103.61 using sudo:

`sudo apt install chromium-browser`

Answer (score 1):

You can build Chromium with H.264 support and all other audio and video formats supported by Google Chrome.
When building Chromium using the official [build instruction](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Install) you need set the following [GN args](https://www.chromium.org/developers/gn-build-configuration):

```
proprietary_codecs=true
ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"
```

**Steps to checkout Chromium release branches**
*Initial setup*

```
mkdir chromium && cd chromium
fetch --nohooks chromium --nosvn=True
gclient sync --with_branch_heads --nohooks # May not even need this.
```

*Fetching/updating a specific release branch*

```
cd src # Assuming that you are already in the above 'chromium' directory.
git fetch origin refs/branch-heads/<branch> # <branch> would be something like '1942'.
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
gclient sync
```

Also, [Advanced Chrome](https://browser.taokaizen.com/) fork does support MP3/MP4/H.264. It is distributed pre-compiled, with no installer. Just unzip, set proper permissions and run it!

Comment: Okay, so how do I get the non-super-unstable source. Like I'm using v83 stable not 86 Canary. I know you can get the source by running apt-get source but I'm not sure what the proper arguments are.

Comment: @Aten I edited my answer, adding instructions to get the code for specific version.